# Objective C: UIButton, UIBarButtonItem, UIBarButtonItemStyle, UIBarButtonSystemItem

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uibutton

I am exploring now the XCode and objective c so in my next project i'll be more familiar with it.

I came across with this UIButton, UIBarButtonItem, UIBarButtonItemStyle, UIBarButtonSystemItem.

What's the difference between those?

How can i use them?

//i know the use of UIButton, i just put it for comparison purposes.

thanks!

Comment: Do you need to know something that's not covered in the exhaustive official documentation with copious sample code that's available in XCode and via Google?

Comment: where can i find that documentation?? i didn't know that there is. i just switched to XCode and Objective C just this month.

Comment: The built-in documentation is available from the Help menu in Xcode. You can install documentation "libraries" from Xcode's preferences under the Downloads tab. The documentation for `UIButton` is also available on the Apple developer site, as the first Google result for "UIButton". The Welcome screen shown when you start Xcode also has links to all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uibarbutton's are used as receivers in an array; and usually presented in a toolbar or navigation bar.  UibarbuttonItemStyle changes the look and feel of the bar button.  Uibarbuttonsystemitem uses an apple-defined button, such as the Done button in the safari toolbar.  All Uibarbutton's can call the same events as UIButtons with the exception of an alpha property (quite annoying).

The documentation listing is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: By the way, excellent use of the //comment part in your question.  Sheer brilliance that I will be stealing from you immediately (LOL)